# Help with count-down clock

Tags: 555

I am quite new to Electrical Engineering and our teacher wanted us to create a circuit diagram. This circuit diagram is supposed to be a 5 minute count-down timer and it is supposed to count-down from 5 minutes to zero, giving a beep every minute.

So every minute it is supposed to make a sound until it reaches 0. I honestly do not know how to create this and will be very thankful if any one of you guys can give me tips or teach me on how to do this.

Also I did do research but honestly, I couldn't find the answer that he was asking for

Thank you

Comment: What has your class taught you about?

Comment: About resistors, capacitors, thermistors etc. He basically taught us about the common components

Comment: He gave us 1 day to finish this off, so rip me

Comment: College class. I am currently doing Level 3 engineering (England)

Comment: You've thus far covered no integrated circuits whatsoever?  No digital logic?  No boolean algebra, nor sequential logic?  I'm a bit shocked that the homework assignment would be so far "out of sequence" with regard to the lectures.

Comment: Closing this as too broad, since OP doesn't even have any approach. This is really like "My teacher told me I have a day to build a car. I've never thought about car design before, and I tagged this with "diesel-motor" because I think diesels do have something to do with it".

Comment: Marcus I understand what you are trying to say but I just don't know how to create a circuit diagram or even build one as we haven't really been taught on how to do this. I just need a bit of help (mainly with the part where it is supposed to make a sound every minute until it reaches 0) so I can start doing it. I don't want you guys to literally to do the whole thing for me, I just need to something to start from

Comment: @V, exactly. There's way too much here for us to answer in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You don't need "just a bit of help", unfortunately.  You appear to have absolutely no foundation, and this is a relatively complex design for an absolute beginner.  To get partial credit, I'd focus on just designing a couple of parts of the project -- both around a 555 (you can find examples of circuits to crib on the internet)  -- something that generates a pulse every second , and something that makes a beep.

Comment: Alright well ty for your help man, @Lawrence.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that he wants you to use 2 or 4 555s. The first is a one-shot with a 300 second pulse output. The output should enable a second 555 set up as an astable with a 60 second pulse rate. So you trigger the first, and it allows the second to put out 5 pulses at 1 minute intervals. You would use the 1 minute pulses to drive a speaker.

To get beeps rather than clicks, you would want the trigger pulse to drive a pair of 555s hooked up just like the first, except that the pulse would be (let's say) 1 second, and the astable set up for 1 kHz. The output of this astable would drive the speaker. So at 1 minute intervals you'd get a 1 second beep at 1 kHz.

Note that this is not actually counting anything, either up or down, so it's technically not what is asked for. However, the question did not ask for a count display, just beeps, so it works the same.

With that said, you can use the 555 data sheet to calculate the component values, but I warn you that the first stage will have very large capacitors, and may not even work properly, due to leakage currents.

Comment: As I was walking down to the cafe, I was wondering if that was the entire PURPOSE of the exercise.  It's a teaching technique that I really *loathe* and would never do to my students.  "Calculate how to get a RC time constant of several minutes" and then use that to lead into a lecture on "The difference between real components and idealized components"

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem into parts .... You need something that counts.  Look at several different counter chips (I'll assume you're building this out of 74x00 logic ... Consider a 74x90 and a 74x92.

You need something to generate a stead stream of pulses to drive the counters.  Your own tag on the question says you know "Consider a 555".  (How precise does this have to be?)

Comment: This is my first time creating a circuit diagram and I am quite confused. Also the reason why I put 555 as my tag is because my question is related to the 555 timer. Also I needed to put a tag in otherwise I wouldn't be able to post this question.

Comment: What do you find confusing?

Comment: The part where he wants the buzzer to make a beeping sound every minute till it reaches 0. Also sorry if I am annoying you, like I said I am new to this

Comment: You're not annoying -- I'm trying to figure out how much you are understanding, and where your information is lacking.  Does the circuit need to have a display, or merely produce five beeps one minute apart and then stop?  Is there anything special that needs to happen on the last beep?

Comment: It doesn't need a display of any sorts, it is just supposed to produce give beeps one minute apart. On the last beep, it just stops.

Comment: Why do you think a 555 is involved if you haven't even learned that ICs exist yet?

Comment: Because he told us to use 555